# Css Sorting and categorization of random data

Tags: css, sorting, flexbox, grid

Say you have the following data points that are dumped from a database or file, the size of each item representing the amount of something (hours, pizzas, whatever)...

[image]

And you would like to organize the data into categories like so *using CSS*...

[image]

How would you do it?

I tried the [grid shepard](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-grid-shepherd-technique-to-order-data-with-css/) method using `grid-row`but get this instead...

[image]

Thanks!

P.S. follow up question... My intuition is that CSS would be faster than JS (...moving each item into the appropriate flexbox that could then sort row members horizontally).  Is that true? Is CSS likely to be faster in a dataset of possibly thousands of elements?

Comment: Do you have any sample CSS that you used to achieve your result?

Comment: @ObsidianAge No, I have not been able to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flexbox`  with `order`.

This is a guide for the flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**check this sample:**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.o-1,.o-3,.o-5,.o-7 {
  background: gold;
}

.o-2,.o-4,.o-6 {
  background: hotpink;
}

.o-1 { order: 1; } 
.o-2 { order: 2; }
.o-3 { order: 3; }
.o-4 { order: 4; }
.o-5 { order: 5; }
.o-6 { order: 6; }
.o-7 { order: 7; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="o-1">1</aside>
  <aside class="o-3">3</aside>
  <aside class="o-2">2</aside>
  <aside class="o-4">4</aside>
  <aside class="o-7">7</aside>
  <aside class="o-5">5</aside>
  <aside class="o-6">6</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox sorts, but not into separate containers/rows. In other words, if the screen were  a million pixels wide, flexbox would just give you a single row of sorted/ordered elements. The question is how sort elements into 3 separate rows.